# Power Automate - trigger an email when one of the field in the sharepoint list is yes

Tags: sharepoint-list, power-automate

I am working on a sharepoint list where there is a field (dropdown- Yes/No) to specify if the mail is to be triggered or no. whenever a user selects "yes" and saves the item, I want an email to be triggered using microsoft flows

Can anyone please advice me how do I do this. Any assistance would be really appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Please [check this post from Powerusers forum](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/SharePoint-list-item-field-updated/m-p/50195#M9171). It contains what you need.

Basically, you need use the SharePoint Connector Trigger for when a SharePoint item is created or modified and then a switch-case on the column value that you want to monitor.

[image]

This flow will trigger every time the list is updated but no actions will be taken if the condition is not met.

[Here is a Microsoft template](https://flow.microsoft.com/en-us/galleries/public/templates/3821506240744debadcd89c94690652d/when-an-item-in-a-sharepoint-list-is-modified-send-an-email/) that you start with to send email when a list is modified. You can tweak it as per your need by adding the switch-case condition.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. :) Will it work if I add condition? I have a field "Mail to be sent" which is a dropdown list - Yes/No. I want the mail to be triggered if the user chooses "Yes" and if the user selects "No" then it should not send any email. I tried using condition where the dynamic field "Mail to be sent Value" is equal to "Yes" but still the condition takes as false when the user select Yes and doesn't trigger the email.

Comment: It might be possible that the field is not taken in to consideration. Please check with any other field to see if there can be other problems like, the actual name of the field to bound to etc. but this is the way to send email through Power Automate.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I did not know that in the condition the value to be matched is case sensitive. That's why it was taking as false. Now, it is working. :) Thank you!

Comment: Please mark this solution as answer if it has helped you.